# Alterar tamanho do GIF gerado pelo FFMPEG

Tags: conversão-de-tipo, vídeo

Estou gerando gifs usando o ffmpeg, na sua última versão (à data desta questão), usando as seguintes linhas de cógido:

```
ffmpeg -y  10  -i in.mp4 -vf fps=10,scale=-1:340:flags=lanczos,palettegen palette.png
```

para gerar uma palete, e

```
ffmpeg -y 10 -i palette.png -fs 8000000 -filter_complex 'fps=10,scale=-1:340:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse=dither=bayer:bayer_scale=5' out.gif
```

para gerar o gif. Tudo funciona bem, só que eu queria diminuir o tamanho (tem 640px de largura) pois o gif é sempre apresentado no máximo com 120px de largura. Como faço para especificar o tamanho? Eu experimentei colocar `-s alturaXlargura` mas dá erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc tem que fazer um filter ***crop*** ou ***scale*** pra setar o tamanho que vc quer. Tipos assim:

Com **scale**:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter:v "scale=w=120:h=120" outFile
```

Com **crop**:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter:v "crop=w=120:h-120" outFile
```

Para determinar onde esse Crop vai começar na imagem original vc tem determinar o X e o Y conforme esse exemplo.

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter:v "crop=w=120:h-120:x-100:y=100" outFile
```

Documentação Oficial do Scale: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale-1

Documentação Oficial do Crop: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop

Vídeo de referência? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPV7JXTWPWI

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

http://www.nerdfirst.net/getting-started-with-ffmpeg/